# How do I calculate the number of workdays between two dates?

Tags: abap

I want to calculate the difference between two dates in ABAP.

My first attempt was to subtract the dates from each other:

```
days_between = date1 - date2.
```

This works but I was wondering if there is a way to calculate only the work days between those two dates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The list of working and off days may vary from a country to another, and from a plant to another. In ABAP-based system, there are calendars already setup for countries, to define which days are working and which ones are off (weekend, holidays). You may also define your own calendar. In a Factory Calendar, each day is assigned a serial integer number (also called a "factory date"), which is +1 between two subsequent working days (off days are ignored).

To work with these calendars, you have to use these officially-released function modules ([SAP Library - Calendar Functions](https://help.sap.com/doc/7a800e67728810148a4b1a83b0e91070/1511%20000/en-US/frameset.htm?48dfbc1aab14280fe10000000a42189c.html)):

- `DATE_CONVERT_TO_FACTORYDATE` : returns the serial number of a given date
- `FACTORYDATE_CONVERT_TO_DATE` : converts a given serial number into a date

To calculate the number of days between two calendar dates, you must first get the serial numbers of these two dates by using `DATE_CONVERT_TO_FACTORYDATE`, and subtract the two serial numbers.

Answer (score 2):

you can use an existing function module like `RKE_SELECT_FACTDAYS_FOR_PERIOD` to calculate the number of working days in a date range. You will need to tell the function module which calendar to use, as this depends on the location (e.g. bank holidays for different countries etc.).

Answer (score 1):

List of working days is a year or/and country specific data, sometimes it might even differ on a base of a country's region. I would check the [CLDR-data](https://cldr.unicode.org), perhaps they provide permanently updated data.

Anyway, I would not advice calculating the date difference with a plain subtract operation, it might be an error prone approach and might lack an edge cases treatment. Instead, it's better to use a dedicated function module (FM) or a class, depending on your codebase guidelines:

- `HR_HK_DIFF_BT_2_DATES`
- `LTRM_TIME_GAP_CALC`
- `CL_RECA_DATE=>GET_DATE_DIFF( )`

The latter is a very powerful class, which contains a lot of useful methods for working with dates.